# Why doesn't Loki use his telekinetic powers more in the Avengers or Thor movies?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, loki

In the recent Thor installment, 'Thor: The Dark World', upon receiving the news of Frigga's death, Loki in his cell, out of anger and frustration uses some form of telekinesis to throw all the furniture in his cell, without physically touching it, by clenching his fists.

This is the first time in the MCU that Loki has been seen using this ability and has yet to be formally addressed and elaborated on.

- If Loki indeed has telekinetic abilities, why did he not use this useful ability during 'The Avengers' or even in the first 'Thor' film.

An ability like that might have proven useful for him in 'The Avengers' movie.

[image]

Comment: Did he really, though? Wasn't the state if his cell an illusion all along, and therefore him "wrecking" it also an illusion?

Comment: It may well be his use is unconscious; released mostly in times he loses control. He was suffering intense grief here.

Comment: He uses his telekinesis a lot more in the Loki TV series.

Answer (score 21):

#### Loki doesn't use telekinesis more because he deems it an insignificant power in comparision to his intellect, his overall sorcerous ability and incomparable genius in getting people to do what he wants.

- He could have certainly used his telekinesis to escape from the cell onboard the helicarrier, except he thought he was TRICKING the Avengers into fighting each other and removing themselves from the playing field.
- Thus the greater deception (in his mind, the higher art) was more important than escaping from the cell. He WANTED to be there.

#### Marvel Canon Comic Universe, Earth-616

**Loki has always had significant magical abilities which allow him to utilize telekinetic powers. He is considered to be one of the most powerful magic users in the Marvel Universe and certainly one of the top five magic users in Asgard.**

> **Loki's sorcerous abilities include:**
>
> - Loki has the ability to generate and control a great quantity of mystical abilities for a variety of purposes, of which can be used to further enhance or augment his physical abilities, like his speed, strength, and stamina, but only temporarily.
> - His magical abilities are equal to Karnilla, the most skilled sorceress in the Asgardian dimension.
> - Being a telekinetic, Loki can influence the movement of objects and people with his mind, and as such, this power proves to be devastating and chaotic in nature.
> - His known abilities include the ability to fire powerful beams of concussive force, generate highly durable force fields, bestow superhuman attributes to living beings or inanimate objects, or teleport himself or others across dimensions.
> - He can also bring inanimate objects to life, or mystically imbue objects or beings with specific but temporary powers. He has, for example, augmented the might of human criminals as the Cobra and Sandu.

- Why doesn't he use these powers more often? Because, comparatively speaking, his telekinetic ability is a relatively weak power among his arsenal.
- More importantly, Loki is a trickster, he is more inclined to want to use the least amount of effort to perform whatever skulduggery he is engaged in. Deception and a well-placed lie are his preferred method of problem-solving, followed closely by shapechanging.

If magic cannot solve the problem, then and only then does the uncivilized use of physical force become an option. He considers physical force to be stooping to Thor's level of problem solving, a definite no-no.

#### Marvel Cinematic Universe, Earth-199999

**Loki in the MCU seems to possess all of the abilities of his canon Earth-616 counterpart. Why he does not utilize his telekinetic ability more is likely similar, he uses telekinesis when it suits him to do so but it is a tool poorly suited for most of his schemes.**